# Matrix of Functions to Function that returns a Matrix

Tags: functions, matrix

I have a $n\times n$ matrix, every entry is of the form

`Function[{t},expr]`

How do I get from that a function `M[t_]`$\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

I made some experiments with `Evaluate` but all I got was a matrix of pure functions.

And `MatrixForm[M[1]]` was evaluated to `(...)[1]`. So the argument was not sent to the "inner" functions.

Comment: If `mat` is you matrix of functions:  `myFun[t_] = mat /. y : Function[__] -> y[t];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this?:

```
mat = ConstantArray[Function[{t}, t^2], {2, 2}]
(*
{{Function[{t}, t^2], Function[{t}, t^2]},
 {Function[{t}, t^2], Function[{t}, t^2]}}
*)

Block[{t},
 Function @@ {{t}, mat[[All, All, 2]]}
 ]

(*  Function[{t}, {{t^2, t^2}, {t^2, t^2}}]  *)
```

Comment: Works perfect for me. And I learned something new.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach. Let's create a small matrix of `Function` objects to play with:

```
m = {{Function[{t}, Sin[t]],  Function[{t}, Cos[t]]},
     {Function[{t}, Sinc[t]], Function[{t}, Tan[t]]}};
```

Then, we can create your `M` function as follows:

```
Clear[mm]
mm[m_][x_] := Map[#[x] &, m, {ArrayDepth[m]}]
```

You can see that passing an argument to mm returns a matrix-valued result:

```
mm[m][2]

(* Out: {{Sin[2], Cos[2]}, {Sinc[2], Tan[2]}} *)
```

This, of course, works for symbolic arguments as well (e.g. `mm[m][e]`).

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[mat_][t_] := Map[Through @ # @ t &] @ mat
```

***Example:***

```
mat = {{Cos, Sin}, {Function[t, t^2], 1 + # &}};

f[mat][t]
```

> ```
>  {{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t^2, 1 + t}}
> ```

```
f[mat][π]
```

> ```
>  {{-1, 0}, {π^2, 1 + π}}
> ```

Also

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[mat_][t_] := Map[Construct[#, t] &, mat, {2}]

f2[mat][t]
```

> ```
> {{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t^2, 1 + t}}
> ```